# Unique strings in arrays, problems with the ubound filter

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Alright I came up with a really complicated way of assigning unique numbers to my table, e.g. RB-001, RB-002... .So the code basically adds all the existing ones into an array (TypeNumArr) in a concatenated form which works, based on what I'm seeing from the `debug.print` . The second bit of code however fails at the `UBound(filter(TypeNumArr,cred))` with an error 13 Type mismatch. I've previously worked with Ubound(filters) to search for unique entries in an array but those arrays were strictly one-dimensional. Does anyone know what is the problem with this one? I suspect it has something to do with the non-one-dimensionality of TypeNumArr since it draws its definition from SBArr which is two-dimensional.

If anyone has a less complicated way of assigning unique numbers to a prefix, ie "RB-" & "001", "002" etc that would be great as well :P

```
'Making a new entry on SB & Reimb
Set TSB = .Worksheets("SB & Reimb").ListObjects(1) 'table name
Set RBrow = TSB.ListRows.Add(1) 'the new row, always add to the top

'Assigning the next # for the RB
SBArr = TSB.DataBodyRange.Value2

For lcount = LBound(SBArr) To UBound(SBArr)
SBArr(lcount, 2) = Right("00" & SBArr(lcount, 2), 3)
TypeNumArr = SBArr(lcount, 1) & "-" & SBArr(lcount, 2)
Debug.Print TypeNumArr
Next lcount

For cred1 = 1 To 999
    cred2 = Right("00" & cred1, 3)
    cred2 = "RB-" & cred2
    Select Case UBound(Filter(TypeNumArr, cred2))
    Case 0
        RBrow.Range(1, 2) = cred1 'all that hard work just to assign a value to the RB
        Exit For
    Case Else
    End Select
Next cred1
```

Comment: When debugging, it is good to split multiple function calls onto separate lines so that you can tell which one is breaking.  In this case, is the issue `UBound` or `Filter`?  Who knows.  If I had to guess, I would say the issue is `Filter` since it expects to see an array in the first parameter and you're passing in a `String`.  That is, `TypeNumArr` is based on `... & "-" & ... ` which will return a string.  If I run similar code over here, `Filter("abcd", "d")`, I get `type mismatch` like you.  you might want to use `InStr()... > 0` if you're just checking if the value contains the number.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to get a list of unique items from a list with duplicates, I put the list into the keys of a dictionary, any duplicates will be discarded.  The dictionary object is in the microsoft scripting runtime library.

```
Dim d As Object
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    d(myArray(i)) = 1
Next i

Dim v As Variant
For Each v In d.Keys()
    'd.Keys() is a Variant array of the unique values in myArray.
    'v will iterate through each of them.
Next v
```